# append alphabet to array via a for loop in C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm just doing practice problems out of my C book and am stuck on this one:

> Write a program that creates an array with 26 elements and stores the 26
>   lowercase letters in it. Also have it show the array contents.

I'm getting stuck here

```
char abc[26];
char index;
for(index="a", abc[0]; index<="z"; index++, abc[0]++){
    abc[]=abc[index]
}
printf("%s", abc);
```

I'm mostly confused on how to append something to an array when its in a for loop, and how to print the entire array.

Comment: 1.  You don't need to append anything to the array here; it's already large enough.  2.  Use a loop to print the array, just like you would use a loop to do anything else with the array.

Comment: Your code will not compile because of a few basic syntax errors. You might want to correct these first.

Comment: `"a"` and `"z"` are not chars; they are pointers to static char arrays; `'a'` and `'z'` are chars. Arrays are zero-based, and `abc['a']` is not zero-based.

Comment: but, how do i get the location in the array abc to ++.  Like how do i get abc[0] to equal 'a' and automatically do this for abc[1] abc[2] and so on.

Comment: `char array[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; printf("%s\n", array);` :-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to append as mentioned in the comments, also be careful with `char i= "a"` and `char i = 'a'`

here is a code, that does create array of 26 lower case alphabet

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    char arr[27];
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<26; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = 'a'+i;
    }

    arr[i]='\0'; //null terminate the array

    printf("%s\n", arr);
}
```